# Boolean value passing to a function not working as expecetd

Tags: function, vb6, boolean

Below code checks whether process is running under WOW64.But now in my below code `iswow64` procedure has parameter of type boolean. But even though variable `sixtyfourbit`  is `true` or `false` the if condition always goes to false condition. Why this happens even though i have passed parameters with proper datatype. Then I passed the same parameter(boolean) as string to `iswow64_string` procedure and it worked properly.  But can anyone tell me what is wrong with passing it as boolean and why it didn't work.

```
Private Declare Function GetProcAddress Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal hModule As Long, _
    ByVal lpProcName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetModuleHandle Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "GetModuleHandleA" _
    (ByVal lpModuleName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetCurrentProcess Lib "kernel32" _
    () As Long

Private Declare Function IsWow64Process Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal hProc As Long, _
    bWow64Process As Boolean) As Long
Private Sub Form_Load()
    sixtyfourbit = Is64bit
    iswow64 (sixtyfourbit)
    iswow64_string (sixtyfourbit)
End Sub
Public Function Is64bit() As Boolean
    Dim handle As Long, bolFunc As Boolean

    ' Assume initially that this is not a Wow64 process
    bolFunc = False

    ' Now check to see if IsWow64Process function exists
    handle = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32"), _
                   "IsWow64Process")

    If handle > 0 Then ' IsWow64Process function exists
        ' Now use the function to determine if
        ' we are running under Wow64
        IsWow64Process GetCurrentProcess(), bolFunc
    End If

    Is64bit = bolFunc

End Function
Public Function iswow64(ByVal sixtyfourbit As Boolean)
    If sixtyfourbit = True Then
        MsgBox ("process running under wow64")
    Else
        MsgBox ("process not running under wow64")
    End If
End Function

Public Function iswow64_string(ByVal sixtyfourbit As String)
    If sixtyfourbit = True Then
        MsgBox ("process running under wow64")
    Else
        MsgBox ("process not running under wow64")
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because of the different ways that `True` and `False` are stored behind the scenes.

- VB6 uses `-1` for `True` and `0` for `False`.
- The Windows API uses `1` for `True` and `0` for `False`. It follows the C convention.

VB6 *doesn't* perform any conversion when an API returns a `Boolean`. It trusts that you got the `Declare` correct, and it just keeps the exact same bits returned by the API.

So in this line

`If sixtyfourbit = True Then`

you are actually comparing `If 1 = -1 Then` and the condition is not true.

It would be better to treat the API values as `Integer` in VB6. Something like this (untested!)

```
Private Declare Function GetProcAddress Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal hModule As Long, _
    ByVal lpProcName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetModuleHandle Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "GetModuleHandleA" _
    (ByVal lpModuleName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetCurrentProcess Lib "kernel32" _
    () As Long

Private Declare Function IsWow64Process Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal hProc As Long, _
    bWow64Process As Integer) As Long 

Private Sub Form_Load()
    sixtyfourbit = Is64bit
    iswow64 (sixtyfourbit)
    iswow64_string (sixtyfourbit)
End Sub
Public Function Is64bit() As Boolean
    Dim handle As Long, bolFunc As Integer

    ' Assume initially that this is not a Wow64 process
    bolFunc = False

    ' Now check to see if IsWow64Process function exists
    handle = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32"), _
                   "IsWow64Process")

    If handle > 0 Then ' IsWow64Process function exists
        ' Now use the function to determine if
        ' we are running under Wow64
        IsWow64Process GetCurrentProcess(), bolFunc
    End If

    Is64bit = (bolFunc <> 0) 

End Function
Public Function iswow64(ByVal sixtyfourbit As Boolean)
    If sixtyfourbit = True Then
        MsgBox ("process running under wow64")
    Else
        MsgBox ("process not running under wow64")
    End If
End Function

Public Function iswow64_string(ByVal sixtyfourbit As String)
    If sixtyfourbit = True Then
        MsgBox ("process running under wow64")
    Else
        MsgBox ("process not running under wow64")
    End If
End Function
```

PS I think your string version works because you have converted the values to Strings, and because the variable is defined as a `Boolean` it has decided to treat `1` as `"True"`. So the comparison is `If "True" = "True" Then`

PPS It is always a good idea to use `Option Explicit`.

Comment: ok. Please have a look at here http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?784499-RESOLVED-Boolean-value-passing-to-a-function-not-working-as-expecetd     Bonnie West has a nice explanation.

Comment: Bonnie is right about some things and wrong about others. I might have to join VB Forums to respond...

Comment: OK, I replied in the other forum and I made some edits above to correct the error Bonnie spotted, and to explain more clearly why (I still think) my main point is correct despite what she said.